# How to dispose a stream after using it in Image?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, graphics, stream

I have the stream of the Image and I convert it into image by the below code

```
Image imagefromstream = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

When I draw this image in graphics, it draws the image.

But, if I dispose the stream after drawing in graphics, the image is not drawn.

Can anyone help me to dispose the image stream

Comment: Show more code of how you draw the image and dispose of the stream please.

Comment: If this is really about WPF, you should not use `System.Drawing.Image` at all, because it is WinForms. Instead, use `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`, as shown in the answer given by Sankarann.

Answer (score 9):

According to MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

`You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.`

You'll have to Dispose the stream when you close your application (or whenever you no longer need the Image)

Comment: what if the MemoryStream is just inside a method block? how could i dispose it after or during application close?

Comment: @PamingkasSevada Use a wrapper `IDisposable` (or `ValueTuple` that you dispose manually) that contains both the `Image` and the `Stream` object together and pass that object around to manage the lifetime of the image.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you have the direct reference of memory stream and if you dispose it, image also will get disposed.

So you get the source from the stream and have it in a `BitmapImage`, set that `BitmapImage` as the source for the Image..

```
var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
imageSource.BeginInit();
imageSource.StreamSource = memoryStream;
imageSource.CacheOption= CacheOption.OnLoad;
imageSource.EndInit();

// Assign the Source property of your image
image.Source = imageSource;
```

Comment: This also works for other streams, not only MemoryStream. You can safely close the stream after `EndInit`.

Comment: Im using .NET 4.8 and image.Source doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Is `BitmapImage` a reference to `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`? If so, that's not really part of `System.Drawing`.